# I simply want to view the contents of shopping cart in Magento

Tags: session, magento, var-dump

I have an observer that is ran when you view the contents of the shopping cart in Magento. I simply want to var_dump the list of product ID's.

I know it probably seems like a dumb question but I can't figure it out and it will help me work out how Magento works.

Thanks in advance

- Alex

Comment: This could be lots of different questions.  Inclue any code you've setup so far so people can point you towards the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `die();` after your var_dump, it should stop execution, and you should see the content of the vardump.

Answer (score 0):

Enable logging: system > configuration > advanced > developer > log settings (make sure the var directory is writable by the web server)
Use:

```
Mage::log($variable);
```

You can use this method anywhere in Magento, e.g. model, block, controller etc
You can find the logged message in magento_dir/var/log/system.log

Answer (score 0):

Exploring Magento without debugger is a hard task. Try to find some time to set up XDebug - it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Each event in Magento has its own specific data attached to it.

You need to provide event being observed, so that people can help you to find out ids of products.